# selecting a variable string name in sql select query in case of stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Suppose I want to select a constant value in an sql query, I could do something like this :

```
select name,age,'tick' from tableA
```

I want to dynamically generating an sql query using stored procedures. For example :

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT CID,DOB, NAME, '+@Scname+' from ' + @TableName
```

Where @TableName, @Scname are dynamically generated variables in a while loop. Here @Scname is interpreted as a column name instead of a constant string when executing query on @TableName. I have tried using escape characters as follows :

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT CID,DOB, NAME, \"'+@Scname+'\" from ' + @TableName
```

But it returns a floating point value full of zeros instead of the string contained in @Scname.

Comment: can you show the final @SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following should work

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT CID,DOB, NAME,'+''''+@Scname+''''+' from '+ @TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT CID,DOB, NAME,' + QUOTENAME(@Scname, '''') + ' from ' + @TableName
```

Comment: Learned something new.